# Gdrive file get JS doesn't work in ie

Tags: internet-explorer, google-drive-api, google-picker

I using this code to retrive file from google drive picker. But on **IE** browser it return error on call.

```
function downloadFile(file, callback) {
if (file.downloadUrl) {
    var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', file.downloadUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        callback(xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
        callback(null);
    };
    xhr.send();
} else {
    callback(null);
}}
```

In Chrome and Firefox works OK, but in IE 11 and + returns "Access denied".
 [Error print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQE12.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IE6 or any old browsers, you'll need to use a specific rpc_relay file and place it in the same domain of your application and then modify its creation code.

**Supporting Older Browsers**

1. Download this file: https://www.google.com/ajax/picker/resources/rpc_relay.html.
2. Place the file somewhere in the same domain as you application.
3. Modify the Picker creation code, using the corrected path:

   ```
   var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
       addView(google.picker.ViewId.IMAGE_SEARCH).
       setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
       setCallback(pickerCallback).
       setRelayUrl('http://www.yoursite.com/somedir/rpc_relay.html').
       build();
   ```

More information about the Picker API can be found in its [documentation](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#top_of_page)

Comment: I was testing on ie11 and edge. I will try this now.